# How to choose shape depending on name in variable?

Tags: vba, excel

This code hides all country flags (shapes) except the German one.
I have a variable that stores the country shortname such as GER, NL etc.

Is there a way to have the corresponding flag visible without creating multiple true/false blocks for each case?

```
'Show proper flag on list and charts
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("GermanyRecommendations").Visible = True
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("NetherlandsRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("AustriaRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("CzechRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("FranceRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("PolandRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("SlovakiaRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("RomaniaRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("SpainRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("BelgiumRecommendations").Visible = False
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes("HungaryRecommendations").Visible = False
```

Comment: You can wrap these stataments in a single loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit concise than @Moosli's solution:

```
Sub SetFlagVisibility(strCountry As String)
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes
       shp.Visible = (shp.Name = strCountry)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code won't hide a visible flag of other than required country if already visible.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Did you test it?

Comment: Oops, my bad, I didn't see the Boolean argument `(shp.Name = strCountry)`.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij ;)

Comment: @JohnyL didn't thought of that. ^^

Comment: @Moosli There's always a shorter way :)

Answer (score 2):

you can loop all Shapes and set all **Shapes Visible = false** and after that just set the shape you want to see to **True**

```
Sub main ()
   Call setShapeVisible("GermanyRecommendations")
End Sub

Sub setShapeVisible(byVal strCountry as String)

Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes
   shp.Visible = False
Next
Worksheets("Recommendations").Shapes(strCountry).Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response that sounds like it almost does the job. Would I be able to somehow have the name of the shape I want to see as a variable? Say I have a variable: flagname, could I somehow insert that instead of "GermanyRecommendations" so that the correct flag shows up depending on the value of the variable?

Comment: Ah I see now, I will test it immediatly thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Put the attached image in the same folder as your sheet. (Sorry, not all flags are there).Name it flags.png.
Put two letter country codes in the cells where the flags are to be displayed.
Select the cells and call this macro:

```
Sub addflag()
Static flags, filepath As String
If flags = vbNullString Then
flags = ":af:al:dz:ad:ao:ag:ar:am:au:at:az:bs:bh:bd:bb" & _
     ":by:be:bz:bj:bt:bo:ba:bw:br:bn:bg:bf:mm:bi:kh" & _
     ":cm:ca:cv:cf:td:cl:cn:co:km:cd:cg:cr:ci:hr:cu" & _
     ":cy:cz:dk:dj:dm:do:tl:ec:eg:sv:gq:er:ee:et:fj" & _
     ":fi:fr:ga:gm:ge:de:gh:gr:gd:gt:gn:gw:gy:ht:hn" & _
     ":hu:ic:in:id:ir:iq:ie:il:it:jm:jp:jo:kz:ke:ki" & _
     ":xk:kp:kr:kw:kg:la:lv:lb:ls:lr:ly:li:lt:lu:mk" & _
     ":mg:mw:my:mv:ml:mt:mh:mr:mu:mx:fm:md:mc:mn:me" & _
     ":ma:mz:na:nr:np:nl:nz:ni:ne:ng:no:om:pk:pw:pa" & _
     ":pg:py:pe:ph:pl:pt:qa:ro:ru:rw:kn:lc:vc:ws:sm" & _
     ":st:sa:sn:rs:sc:sl:sg:sk:si:sb:so:za:es:lk:ps" & _
     ":sr:sz:se:ch:sy:tw:tj:tz:th:tg:to:tt:tn:tr:tm" & _
     ":tv:ug:ua:ae:gb:us:uy:uz:vu:va:ve:vn:ye:zm:zw"
     filepath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\flags.png"
End If
Const nr = 13
Const nc = 15
Dim cll As range

Dim sh As Shape
Dim ss As String
Dim xr, xc, pos, r, c  As Long
Dim vv As Variant

Dim offr, offc As Long
offr = nr \ 2
offc = nc \ 2

For Each cll In Selection.Cells
  vv = cll.Value
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(vv) Then
    ss = CStr(vv)
    If Len(ss) = 2 Then
      pos = CLng(InStr(1, flags, ss, vbTextCompare))
      If pos <> 0 Then
        pos = (pos - 2) \ 3
        r = offr - (pos \ nc)
        c = offc - (pos Mod nc)
        Debug.Print ss, pos, r, c
        With cll
          Dim w, h
          w = .Width
          h = .Height
          Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(filepath, msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, w, h)
          With sh
           .Top = cll.Top
           .Left = cll.Left
           .Height = h
           .Width = w
           .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
           With .PictureFormat.Crop
             .PictureWidth = nc * w
             .PictureHeight = nr * h
             .PictureOffsetX = c * w
             .PictureOffsetY = r * h
           End With
         End With
        End With
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image: flags spritesheet]