# How can I duplicate a shape in a different Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have a sprite  sheet with country flags and code that puts the shape of a flag in each cell of a selection with two letter country codes.
This works well if i .Addpicture from an external .png file for each cell.
When i try to put the .png in an auxiliary sheet and .Duplicate flags from it, the flags are created in the sheet where the spritesheet is, no matter what I try. Stripped example below

How Can I .Duplicate a shape in a different Sheet?

```
Dim sh,shf as shape
dim is as range
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set shf = Worksheets("flags").Shapes("flags")
ws.Activate
...
For each i in Selection.Cells
           'get country code and calculate offsets 
           Set sh = shf.Duplicate   'this puts the shape in the flags sheet
....
```

Comment: Hi,  have you checked [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.duplicate] ? The method does not offer the option to duplicate in a different location.  I think what you need to do is use this method [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.copypicture] and then paste the content of the clipboard on the sheet where you wish to.  Hope his helps.

Comment: I had read the manual page about .Duplicate, unfortunately its too terse and forgets to state the copy goes always to the sheet the original shape is in. Thanks!

Comment: See, that's why I suggested to use Copy-Paste instead :-)

Comment: BTW. I published here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920622/is-there-a-way-to-choose-the-correct-country-flag-depending-on-country-name-in-v the country flag macro that uses an external spritesheet file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As according to other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088220/excel-vba-macro-to-move-shapes-to-a-different-shape-without-copying-and-past) found, you cannot just move a shape from one sheet to another, and `.Duplicate` will just duplicate in the same place.

Easiest step might be to just [copy and paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950757/excel-copy-shapes-from-one-worksheet-to-another) the shape to the new worksheet. Giving it a new name in the process.

```
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim shp2 As Shape

Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("flags")

s2.Shapes(yourflag).copy
s1.Paste
set shp2 = s1.Shapes(s1.shapes.count)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The answer you link to does'n mention .Duplicate at all....

Comment: That's true. They mention that there's "there is no location property or move method", so I added that .Duplicate will just make another shape in the same place. It was intended more as some added info to back up my claims.

Comment: If you really want to move your shape, just use `.cut` instead of `.copy`.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been stated, the `Duplicate` method does not offer the possibility to do that in a different sheet. But you can cut and paste the duplicated shape in the next way (in case you like duplicate and not using the clasic Copy - Paste solution):

```
Sub testShapeDuplicate()
 Dim sh As Shape, shf As Shape, dLeft As Double, dTop As Double
  Set shf = = Worksheets("flags").Shapes("flags")
  Set sh = shf.Duplicate 
  sh.Name = "Dupl": dLeft = shf.left: dTop = shf.top
  sh.Cut
  With ActiveSheet.Next 'it will be moved in the next sheet. Use here what sheet you need, please
    .Paste
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.count)
        .left = dLeft: .top = dTop 'put the shape in the same position
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Besides that, when you declare `Dim sh,shf as shape`, only the `shf` object is declared `As Shape`. `sh` is declared `As Variant`...